# Facebook Open Graph Images are Low Quality For Rotated Images

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I use the Facebook Open Graph to publish URLs from a website to their corresponding Facebook Page. The main image is specified using the Open Graph tag `og:image`. Sometimes the images show up on Facebook as a very zoomed-in, and granular/pixelated. Upon further examination, the images which do poorly appear to have been rotated (I noticed this because a Lightbox plugin I use isn't correctly rotating them, but all other software: browser, Mac Preview, Facebook are).

An [example page](http://www.morphmarket.com/c/reptiles/pythons/ball-pythons/36079) from the site with the problem (click to zoom and see the orientation issue in that 3rd party library but that's another matter). **This issue I'm trying to resolve on Facebook can be seen by using the [Facebook Debugger against this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.morphmarket.com%2Fc%2Freptiles%2Fpythons%2Fball-pythons%2F36079).** (As a side-note, it's oriented correctly).

At first I thought I could perhaps fix this with `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`, but it had no effect (it did fix a different [the pre-caching/crawling issue](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images)).

Note that providing the [raw image URL](https://morphmarket-media.s3.amazonaws.com/media/raw_images/repterra/2016/08/20160822143729-image.jpeg) directly into the Debugger [works fine](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmorphmarket-media.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fmedia%2Fraw_images%2Frepterra%2F2016%2F08%2F20160822143729-image.jpeg); the problem is only when providing this URL via the Open Graph tags.

My one workaround idea is to use my image processing library (sorl-thumbnail) to produce a version of the image which FB might like better.

**What is the specific characteristic of these rotated images causing a problem and how do I work around it?**

Comment: I’m having a hard time figuring out what the actual question is here. Anyway, you might want to have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: @CBroe, 1. The question is (was already) the thing in bold at the end with a question mark. 2. That link is already a cited reference in my question.

Comment: I have no idea what “rotation” you are talking about here - the image the debug tool shows as preview is clearly a portion of the og:image you specified, https://morphmarket-media.s3.amazonaws.com/media/raw_images/repterra/2016/08/20160822143729-image.jpeg – but no “rotation” involved, it is just the top portion of that image cropped & scaled.

Comment: @CBroe, that is what I said "As a side-note, it's oriented correctly". However, I can tell you from experience that the only images FB is having problems with are those with EXIF orientation flags, like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a legitimate Facebook bug. Kudos to them for responding and addressing it promptly.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1080037355413437/